# Cold stuffed mushrooms?

Tags: mushrooms, stuffing

I was planning on making some stuffed mushrooms for a halloween party at work (I am going as Mario), however there aren't any suitable ovens at work and my commute is long and in the early AM so they will obviously not stay hot en route.

So the question is, how can I adapt a recipe to be cold or room temperature and that it will still taste good?

Should I still bake the mushrooms, but then add the cold stuffing mixture later when I get there? Just not sure how to go.

I am making 2 kinds, veggie and crab. I have crab meat, broccoli, cream cheese, green onions, salt, parsley, garlic powder, and a bunch of seasonings. I was going to try and come up with a good mixture...

Got any ideas?

Comment: I have a 12 inch George Foreman, which is good for helping me contribute warm potluck for office - like chicken biryani burito, where I need the George Foreman to seal the burrito with melted cheese. It's a very handy machine. I bake pizza with it. Fry cashews in garam masala paste with it.

Comment: It seems that your question is primarily about hot vs. cold mushrooms, and so the last two paragraphs (which seem to be asking for stuffing recipes) seem extraneous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, cold food needs stronger flavors to taste equally good.  A little more seasoning, a little stronger spicing, a touch more acidity.

However, you also have to consider texture and cultural expectations.

I am not sure that cold cooked mushrooms are... expected.  You might want to try it in advance and see what you think.  On the other hand, raw mushrooms would be dissonant as well with stuffing.

I would suggest reassessing what you are taking.  Perhaps a crudite, where your fillings transform into dips, and you supplement the (raw) mushrooms with other vegetables might be a logistically more appropriate dish.

If you want hot dips, they can probably be done in a microwave, if your office has one.

Comment: Good points. I think there are actually some toaster ovens there and I'll bring one, so perhaps I can (in a few batches) get them tasting toasty hot. Probably worth the effort to cook it, if not I'd better think of something else.